# How to fix additional STA driver installation error on 12.04

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I have a Broadcom BCM4313 wireless driver. It worked fine under 11.04 and the upgrade to 11.10 also went smoothly. The 12.04 upgrade has broken the wireless connection. I've seen several posts about this and all presume you can activate the STA drivers, but that's where it fails on this machine.

The log is in /var/log/jockey.log:

```
WARNING: modinfo for module wl failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module wl

WARNING: /sys/module/wl/drivers does not exist, cannot rebind wl driver
DEBUG: BroadcomWLHandler enabled(): kmod disabled, bcm43xx: blacklisted, b43: blacklisted, b43legacy: blacklisted

(repeat of last error several times)
```

Any ideas how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If there are errors, please post them here.

Comment: Thanks, reinstalling bcmwl-kernel-source activated the STA drivers without me having to do any more. 
I also removed b43-fwcutter because I read in other posts that the current b43 drivers may clash with the STA drivers and are not compatible with the BCM4313. Is that correct?

Comment: b43 does conflict however, installation of bcmwl-kernel-source blacklists it six ways from Sunday. There should be no problem at all.